# How does g++ find the Standard libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, centos, g++

So I'm currently trying to compile something with a newer version of g++ (4.7) than the version of CentOS 6.5.

I'm running supports through yum. I've got a 4.7 g++ binary ready to go, and switched the linking so that /usr/bin/g++ links to the binary I want.

This has been working, but now g++ can't find any of the c++ standard libraries (for instance `<algorithm>` and `<iostream>`).

I was wondering how g++ loads these libraries / where these libraries are kept so I can figure out how to get them to properly import!

Thanks!

Comment: g++ uses some form of black magic to find them. :-). Ok... quips aside, AFAIK, the path to STL headers is hardcoded into g++, the library path can be altered with Environment Variables and flags... To change the part to STL headers, you may have to recompile gcc...

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple installations of GCC you can direct the `gcc`|`g++` frontend (`/usr/bin/{gcc|g++}`)
to use the tools, headers and libraries of any of them by means
of the [`-B`*prefix*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) 
option, where *prefix* is an installation prefix.

For example, I have GCC 4.9.3 installed (per distro) with prefix:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
```

and also have GCC 5.2.1 installed (also per distro) with prefix:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1
```

If I invoke:

```
gcc -B/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3...
```

then I'm using the 4.9 tools, headers and libraries. If I invoke:

```
gcc -B/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1...
```

then I'm using the 5.2 tools, headers and libraries. If I omit
`-B`*prefix* then I get my latest installation (5.2).